# Repeated messages from Emacs packages Ergoemacs and Helm

Tags: emacs

On starting emacs, two packages(ergoemacs and helm) repeatedly are enabled or turned on. I have pasted some of it below. The *Message* buffer contains 3-4 times the messages pasted below

`Ergoemacs-mode turned ON.
Helm completion enabled
Ergoemacs-mode turned ON.
Helm completion enabled
Ergoemacs-mode turned ON.
Helm completion enabled
Ergoemacs-mode turned ON.
Helm completion enabled
Ergoemacs-mode turned ON.
Helm completion enabled...`

I have a simple emacs setup with all my customizations in .emacs.d/init.el, starting with customizations for ErgoEmacs and then some packages and then Helm settings at the end.

EDIT: I apologize for not posting my init file. Thank you for kindly reminding me :). Here it is: http://pastebin.com/bDYHEEuB. My message buffer: http://pastebin.com/z5Dy7hFf

Comment: I think we'll probably have to see the relevant part of your init.el to see what's going on here.

Comment: Try commenting out one or the other. Does such repetition occur when only one of those packages is used? That at least tells you whether the problem is an interaction between the two or is caused by one of them independently.

Comment: Does that repetition at least stop at some point, or does it go on indefinitely. And yes, as @RAbraham has said, please show us some of your init file - it's hard to read minds. ;-)

Comment: I have pasted my init and message buffer. Thank you for trying to help me.